# Return a sorted ordering of courses such that we can finish all courses

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming

The task:

> We're given a hashmap associating each courseId key with a list of
>   courseIds values, which represents that the prerequisites of courseId
>   are courseIds. Return a sorted ordering of courses such that we can
>   finish all courses.
>
> Return null if there is no such ordering.
>
> For example, given `{'CSC300': ['CSC100', 'CSC200'], 'CSC200':
>   ['CSC100'], 'CSC100': []}`, should return `['CSC100', 'CSC200',
>   'CSCS300']`.

My solution:

```
const isEveryCourseCovered = courses => courses.every(c => !Boolean(c));
const getCourseOrder = courses => {
  const courseSubjects = Object.keys(courses);
  const courseRequirements = Object.values(courses);
  const courseOrder = [];

  do {
    courseSubjects.map((subject, i) => {
      if (subject) {
        courseRequirements[i].map((requirement, idx) => {
          if (courseOrder.includes(requirement)) {
            courseRequirements[i].splice(idx, 1);
          }
        });
        if (!courseRequirements[i].length) {
          courseOrder.push(subject);
          delete courseSubjects[i];
        }
      }
    });
  } while(!isEveryCourseCovered(courseSubjects));

  return courseOrder;
};

const coursesObj = {'CSC300': ['CSC100', 'CSC200'], 'CSC200': ['CSC100'], 'CSC100': []};
console.log("result ", getCourseOrder(coursesObj));
```

Comment: Should the values be sorted by (alpha-) numeric order? e.g. if the input was `{'CSC400': ['CSC200'], 'CSC300': ['CSC100', 'CSC200'], 'CSC200': ['CSC100'], 'CSC100': []};` then should the output be `[ "CSC100", "CSC200", "CSC300", "CSC400"]`?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ following the pattern of the post, i assume `CSC400` would have an array of courses required to get to it, `'CSC400': ['CSC100', 'CSC200', 'CSC300'],`

Comment: @Taki you can’t assume CS300 would be a pre-requisite of CS400. Some institutions *might* not have such a pattern- e.g. if both are elective courses like graphics and networking

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ oh didn't know that, fair enough, but again, it's just an assumption following the pattern in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Objects are passed by "copy of a reference".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Notice that the `coursesObj` after the function call has empty values ( see snippet below )

```js
const isEveryCourseCovered = courses => courses.every(c => !Boolean(c));
const getCourseOrder = courses => {
  const courseSubjects = Object.keys(courses);
  const courseRequirements = Object.values(courses);
  const courseOrder = [];

  do {
    courseSubjects.map((subject, i) => {
      if (subject) {
        courseRequirements[i].map((requirement, idx) => {
          if (courseOrder.includes(requirement)) {
            courseRequirements[i].splice(idx, 1);
          }
        });
        if (!courseRequirements[i].length) {
          courseOrder.push(subject);
          delete courseSubjects[i];
        }
      }
    });
  } while (!isEveryCourseCovered(courseSubjects));

  return courseOrder;
};

const coursesObj = {
  'CSC300': ['CSC100', 'CSC200'],
  'CSC200': ['CSC100'],
  'CSC100': []
};
console.log("result ", getCourseOrder(coursesObj));

console.log("Courses Object : ", coursesObj);
```

You should create a copy of the passed object, a quick way ( [one of many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) ) of doing that is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));`
( see snippet below ):

```
const getCourseOrder = c => {
  // make a copy of the input object
  const courses = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));
```

```js
const isEveryCourseCovered = courses => courses.every(c => !Boolean(c));
const getCourseOrder = c => {
  // make a copy of the input object
  const courses = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));

  const courseSubjects = Object.keys(courses);
  const courseRequirements = Object.values(courses);
  const courseOrder = [];

  do {
    courseSubjects.map((subject, i) => {
      if (subject) {
        courseRequirements[i].map((requirement, idx) => {
          if (courseOrder.includes(requirement)) {
            courseRequirements[i].splice(idx, 1);
          }
        });
        if (!courseRequirements[i].length) {
          courseOrder.push(subject);
          delete courseSubjects[i];
        }
      }
    });
  } while (!isEveryCourseCovered(courseSubjects));

  return courseOrder;
};

const coursesObj = {
  'CSC300': ['CSC100', 'CSC200'],
  'CSC200': ['CSC100'],
  'CSC100': []
};
console.log("result ", getCourseOrder(coursesObj));

console.log("Courses Object : ", coursesObj);
```

I didn't test the performance but i would guess it wouldn't be that efficient since it has 5 nested loops (`do while`, `.map`, `.map`, `.includes`) and `.every` that's called on every iteration of the `while` loop and 3 `if`s

Reading the requirement :

> Return a **sorted** ordering of courses

[Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) was the first thing to come to my mind, my suggested approach would be simply sorting the `Object.keys` of the `coursesObj` based on the length of the value ( array of required courses) corresponding to that key, like so :

```js
const coursesObj = {
  'CSC300': ['CSC100', 'CSC200'],
  'CSC400': ['CSC100', 'CSC200', 'CSC300'],
  'CSC200': ['CSC100'],
  'CSC100': []
};

const result = Object.keys(coursesObj).sort((a, b) =>
  coursesObj[a].length - coursesObj[b].length
);

console.log(result)
```

PS : i added the `CSC400` key in the middle just for the demo.

**EDIT :**

If you have an Object like :

```
const coursesObj = 
    {  
      c1: ['c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 
      c5: ['c1'], 
      c4: [], 
      c2: [], 
      c3: ['c4']
    }
```

you can transform it to add the prerequisites of the courses in its prerequisites 
 array so it becomes :

```
const detailed = 
   { 
     c1: [ 'c2', 'c3', 'c4' ],​​​​​
     c5: [ 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4' ],​​​​​ // c5 now has c1 and the prerequisites of c1
   ​​​​​  c4: [],​​​​​
​​​​​     c2: [],​​​​​
   ​​​​​  c3: [ 'c4' ] 
   }​​​​​
```

then apply the same sort function above :

```js
const coursesObj = { c1: ["c2", "c3", "c4"], c5: ["c1"], c4: [], c2: [], c3: ["c4"] };

const detailedObj = Object.entries(coursesObj).reduce((accumulator, [courseId, requirements]) => {
  accumulator[courseId] = requirements.slice(0); // original courses required.

  requirements.forEach(course => {
    accumulator[courseId].push(...coursesObj[course]); // add the required courses for each required course .
  });

  // remove the duplicates
  accumulator[courseId] = [...new Set(accumulator[courseId])];

  return accumulator;
}, {});

// sort by the number of prerequisites 
const result = Object.keys(detailedObj).sort((a, b) =>
  detailedObj[a].length - detailedObj[b].length
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. There are something I definitely will take into account. But I'm not sure, whether the solution you presented is correct. The sorting can't be done by the length of the array alone but has to be in relation to the required courses. E.g. `const coursesObj = {
 'c1': ['c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
  'c5': ['c1'],
  'c4': [],
  'c2': [],
  'c3': ['c4'],
};` should return this order `{c4, c2, c3, c1, c5}`

Comment: @thadeuszlay i updated the answer for the input you provided,